# What do we mean address(0) in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I was going through the solidity doc and this contract example.

Check the contract `Ballot`.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/solidity-by-example.html

I seem to get most part. However the below code confuses me. What do we mean by address(0) here?

[image]